# How to edit, delete and add in php mysql without jquery or java script?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete , edit and add new recodes on the same page but it seems am failing to make it work .And I do not want to do it using ajax jquery or java script but only php .I need some help please below are my code :

```
<?php
include_once('con.php');

$strSQL = "SELECT film_id, name
from
filmsbox";
$rs     = mysql_query($strSQL);
echo "<table border='1' ><tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td>Name</td> <td colspan='2'>Action</td></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $film_id = $row['film_id'];
    $name    = $row['name'];

    $hometeam= mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#eeeee'><td>$name</td> <td><a href='index.php?film_id=$film_id' name ='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='index.php?film_id=$film_id' name ='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

}
?>
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT film_id, name
from
filmsbox";
$rs     = mysql_query($strSQL);
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$film_id= $row['film_id'];
$name   = $row['name'];

$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

$film_id= $_GET['film_id'];
?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
    ?>
    <table>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type = "text" name = "name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input name="film_id" type="hidden" id="film_id" value="<?php echo $film_id; ?>">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="update">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']))? trim($_POST['name']): '';
    $film_id = $_POST['film_id'];
    $sql     = "UPDATE filmsbox SET name='$name'
    WHERE film_id ='$film_id'";
    $result  = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>
<?php
/*Delete section*/
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $film_id = $_GET['film_id'];
    $delete  = "DELETE FROM filmsbox WHERE film_id = '$film_id'";
    $result  = mysql_query($delete);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Record deleted successfuly ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No data deleted";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please give some specific error that you encounter,so that others can help.No one understands what the issue is and we cannot run your code also!

Comment: It would be **very helpful** to know what is not working.

Comment: There is no jquery/ javascript defined!

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir i DO NOT WANT TO USE ANY BUT php only and thanks alot for the edit

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir Your comment is getting upvotes but I still don't get the reason for it. He stated in the question that he doesn't wanna use  it so why should it be defined? :S

Comment: i think you forgot to define the hidden field named "edit" in your edit portion, then it will come and update it.

Comment: He has already putted the non jquery/javascript solution so why he is asking

Comment: He has problems with getting the non js sollution to work. Obvious for me but never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of pointers:

1. You only need to escape values before they go into the database, not when they come out and are used in HTML i.e `$hometeam = mysql_real_escape_string($name);`
2. You are pulling the same query from the database twice in quick succession which is not needed.  You can remove one of the 2 `$strSQL = "SELECT film_id, name
   from 
   filmsbox";
   $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);` sections from the top of your code
3. You need to run any update/delete queries on the data before you then do your select query to pull out the records for the page, otherwise your changes will not be shown
4. You should be escaping the values for your update and delete queries to prevent SQL injection

Edit:
To reload the page in an edit mode, you need to change the link URL in the table to something like

```
<a href='index.php?film_id=$film_id&edit=1' name ='edit'>Edit</a>
```

Then your edit block needs to be

```
if ($_GET['edit']) {
```

I want to be clear this is not in any way a secure method of editing values, as anyone can put `?edit=1` on the url and get to the form

Comment: Great but <a href="" name='edit'> does it get recognised as $_POST['edit'] ?

Comment: No it wouldn't.  The default for an `a` tag is to send a $_GET request.  And then only by reloading the page using the `href` attribute with something like `href="index.php?edit=1"`  $_POST is only filled via form submissions with a `method` attribute of POST

Comment: and if I delete b4 how will the code know the ID am trying to delete ?

Comment: so you mean instead of post I use get?

Comment: As for your delete, you get the ID from the $_GET as well using the delete link.  I think you may want to read up a little on $_GET and $_POST as your code shows you are not using them correctly.

Comment: Just extending the pointers: Instead of mysql_ functions, use PDO class. mysql_ functions are deprecated, and PDO'll save you headaches later, when you'll insert/update strings into the database. PDO PHP manual => http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php, PDO tutorial => http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: its a shool assignment they need us to use mysql_function

Comment: <a href='index.php?film_id=$film_id&edit=1' name ='edit'>Edit</a> why we put a value of one ? and doues also apply to the delete part ?

Comment: The value of 1 is just to provide a truthy value that will cause the `if ($_GET['edit'])` block to be executed.  Yes also required in delete link

Comment: am get it now but am geting a little confused lts assume I delete the edit part and I wanna firt make sure the delete part works first can I do like that after the diplaying of the data?: if(isset($_Get['delete']))
{
    $film_id = $_GET['film_id'];
    $delete  = "DELETE FROM filmsbox WHERE film_id = '$film_id'";
    $result  = mysql_query($delete);
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Record deleted successfuly ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No data deleted";
    }
}

Comment: If you do the delete after displaying the data, your deleted record will still be visible in the table.  You __must__ do the delete/update before the display if you want the table to only show correct information

Comment: sORRY TO BATHER U MUCH BUT i DO NOT KNW WATS WRONG PLEASE CHAECK ON THIS CODE http://pastebin.com/7YsP7Ctx

Comment: from there maybe u will be able to tell me the mistake

Comment: You're still not using the _GET and _POST correctly...!  And you still have the SELECT query before the DELETE... I've made some changes here but you need to read them, read up on _GET and _POST http://pastebin.com/sfGbKu0d